# is this the right way to fetch data while usine usestate hooks? i use usestate hook but i don't know if this the right way to fetch data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

[image]

i just wrote the code and fetch usestate data like that cause I didn't find some source to how doing it
in the form section I use onChange={event => setFirstName(event.target.value)} I don't know where is the problem cause the data didn't show up in the database

```
function OrderCP(props) {
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [mobileNumber, setMobileNumber] = useState('');
  const [adress, setAddress] = useState('');
  const [city, setCity] = useState('');
  const [size, setSize] = useState('');
  const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState('1');






  function onOrderSubmit ()  {
  fetch('http://localhost:3000/orderCP', {
      method: 'post',
      mode: 'cors',
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      body: JSON.stringify({
        firstname: setFirstName,
        lastname:setLastName,
        email: setEmail,
        mobilenumber: setMobileNumber,
        adress: setAddress,
        city: setCity,
        size:setSize,
        quantity: setQuantity

      })
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(user => {
        if (user.id) {
         return (
          this.props.loadUser(user),
         <Link to ='/orderCP/orderCompletedCP' /> )
        }
      })
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the "set" methods are functions to set the values of the useState variables.

For example

```
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('')
```

the status of firstName is initial an empty string.
To set the variable you call

```
setFirstName('newString')
```

after that you can use firstName to access the value.

You should change your body

```
`body: JSON.stringify({
    firstname: firstName,
    lastname:lastName,
    email: email,
    mobilenumber: mobileNumber,
    adress: address,
    city: city,
    size:size,
    quantity: quantity

  })`
```

Comment: and for calling the loadUser function and `<Link to ='/orderCP/orderCompletedCP' />` is that the right way change route @Stevetro

Comment: what do u think

Comment: @MAMOCHACH no, you rendering the link component, you could just use the navgiator to navigate the desired route. Depens on which navigator you are using